# Can't get input data from form LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

I'm learning Laravel and I got stuck trying to get data from a form.

I already am able to get data back with GET, but with POST I've been having a ton of trouble. Here's what I'm working with:

Form:

```
<form id="forms" method="POST" action="sugestoes" novalidate>

  {{ csrf_field() }}

  <div class="form-row">

    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label for="obs">Observações:</label>
      <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="obs" placeholder="Observações" required></textarea>
    </div>

  </div>

    <hr>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>

</form>

  @php 

  if (isset($_POST["obs"])) {
    echo "IN";
  }

  @endphp
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->input('obs');

        return redirect('sugestoes');


        //
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('sugestoes', 'PostController@store');
```

The intended behaviour that I'm trying to reach is for the post to be submitted, and then returning to the same page with an empty form. Later on I'll be sending the input data into a database, but for now I just want to get the post to work.

I guess I'm missing something really basic, but I've been following guides and looking online, I've done some progress but I'm really stuck here.

(some more info, this is Laravel 5.4, and I'm using XAMPP)

Comment: $_POST isn't maintained through a redirect.

Comment: you need to pass data using with method redirect('sugestoes')->with(your data);

Comment: @Madhusudan, that still won't maintain $_POST.  That will flash session data.

Comment: @Devon that's why I suggest with a method to pass data to view.

Comment: fyi & OT: your `<label>`'s `for` attribute should point to an `id` of a form element, so add `id="obs"` to your `<textarea>`

Comment: I think form submission URL is not given?

Comment: Thanks kerbholz, I did have that id set up before, but I deleted while testing because I thought it might be conflicting with the "name" with the same name. I will add the id again, thanks for the tip!

Comment: The URL is given @DPS, you can see `action` in the form and also in the route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to call the model, `use App/Your_model_name;` then you have to save the data.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Suggest; //Suggest model, let's hope you have suggest table

class PostController extends Controller
{

  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    $suggest = new Suggest; //model
    $suggest->name = $request->obs; //name is DB name, obs is request name
    $suggest->save(); //save the post to DB

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Saved successfully'); //return back with message
  }
}
```

Then if you want to flash the message on the HTML page

```
@if(session('success'))
  <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" id="error-alert">
     <strong style="color: white;">{{session('success')}}</strong>
  </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Just to make sure I'm getting this right: I will need to add the input data to a database in order to keep it throught a redirect? There's no other simple way to achieve what I'm trying to do, right?

Comment: Redirect is usually used in `method-post`, yes I think this way is the easiest way to save data into DB, please read more about HTTP-redirect https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redirects

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will save it for future reference, once I go to the next step (which is saving the post data into DB) this will be very useful for sure!
Right now I was just trying to make sure the input data was being saved by the post method without saving it into a db, hence that echo with the POST data. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: I've never heard about input data is saved by post method, maybe I'm too dumb.. You want input data to go through controller and then return back to the page with a flash message?

Comment: Ye, that was what I intended. If it is not possible, then my bad, and I will follow on to the next step with is saving to the DB.

Comment: This is the examplof flashing/printing the `success/error` message in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Comment: You can store inside the variable, but not save. And you can used also. But please try to do saving into DB automatically, and you'll understand better

Comment: Thanks, but what I mean by saving is storing in the variable at this point. I try to echo "IN" is POST is set, but that never works. Thats my issue

Comment: If you want to check the data from DB then you have to call the `get()` method, then after that your `echo "in"` will work (if data is there), If you just want to store as variable then you have to write other condition to `echo` the message

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="forms" method="POST" action="{{ route('sugestoes') }}" novalidate>
 {{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="form-row">

<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <label for="obs">Observações:</label>
  <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="obs" placeholder="Observações" required></textarea>
 </div>

</div>



   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>

  </form>
```

Remove the @php tag below the form, then in router.php

```
Route::post('/sugestoes', 'PostController@store')->name('sugestoes');
```

Then in Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->input('obs');

   return redirect('/sugestoes'); // you should have GET in Route.php


    //
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I have the php tags below the form to test if it is working. Maybe I'm missing something..? Regardless, I've tried your tips and the result is the same: I get redirected to the empty form(as intended) but there's no indication that what I submitted previously was saved into $_POST.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following code in your action attribute on the form. It will capture the post URL. When you submit the form it will send the form data to the URL end-point.

```
action="{{ url('sugestoes')}}"
```

Then die and dump in your controller store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());

}
```

Comment: How would this help? Please clarify.

Comment: Really he asked for a basic help means he knows what he is doing @Script47

Comment: so how does your answer will help